# How much RAM is SQL Server actually using?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ram

I am debugging one of my apps and noticed that the RAM on my SQL Server 2005 x64 box (running on a Windows 2003 R2 x64 ) is pegged and even going into the paging file.

I understand that SQL Server 2005 x64 just grabs everything it can, so this might be normal (???).  How can I check how much memory it is actually using?

Comment: You should explore SQL Server\Memory Manager performance counters.

Comment: Isn't this a ServerFault question?

Comment: select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to run Perfmon (start->control panel->administrative tools->performance).  The counters you want, I believe, are in SQL Server:Memory Manager.  Target Server Memory is how much it's allowed to take if needed, Total Server Memory is how much it's currently using.  If you click on Explain it'll pop open a box with the details.

By default it's uncapped, and should use all but a couple gb of memory (it leaves that for the OS).  However, there are various bugs and memory leaks that can cause it to go into paging.

Comment: What bugs are you referring to? There are many legitimate reasons why SQL might need to page, one being if the server is starved of physical memory (RAM). If there is no RAM available SQL has no choice but to use the disk.

Comment: All this does for me is show a graph that is continually '100', which is impossible.

Comment: Vasili, change the graph type to "report"

Answer (score 10):

Related to your question, you may want to consider limiting the amount of RAM SQL Server has access to if you are using it in a shared environment, i.e., on a server that hosts more than just SQL Server:

1. Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005: SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Connect using whatever account has admin rights.
3. Right click on the database > Properties.
4. Select "Memory" from the left pane and then change the "Server memory options" to whatever you feel should be allocated to SQL Server.

This will help alleviate SQL Server from consuming all the server's RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Total Server Memory is NOT how much memory SQL Server is currently using.

refer to this Microsoft article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190924.aspx

Comment: Which counter(s) should I be looking at?

Answer (score -1):

Go to management studio and run `sp_helpdb <db_name>`, it will give detailed disk usage for the specified database.  Running it without any parameter values will list high level information for all databases in the instance.

Comment: The question was about memory (RAM) usage, rather than disk usage.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way to see ram usage if you have RDP access / console access would be just launch task manager - click processes - show processes from all users, sort by RAM - This will give you SQL's usage.

As was mentioned above, to decrease the size (which will take effect immediately, no restart required) launch sql management studio, click the server, properties - memory and decrease the max. There's no exactly perfect number, but make sure the server has ram free for other tasks.

The answers about perfmon are correct and should be used, but they aren't as obvious a method as task manager IMHO.

Comment: This does not work.. It shows 300 Mb but if restart the SQL server I get 8gb more free memory

Comment: Do you have CLR routines perhaps? Those can use ram and be freed when sql stops.

Comment: Nope we are not using clr routines..

Comment: The mwmory usage in Task Manager for sqlservr.exe is usually a lie - see http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/

Answer (score -6):

1. Start -> Run -> perfmon
2. Look at the zillions of counters that SQL Server installs

Comment: downvote because there are so many sql perf counters that are unrelated to memory and looking at "the zillions" doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: It's still a nice hint.