# SQL Server memory Utilization

Tags: sql-server

**Question:**

How to I get memory utilization by SQL-server ?

**What I have tried:**

I am using, below select query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

for getting my answer but it not gives the exact memory value which used by SQL-server .

Comment: Code and Text formatting

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to DX.
You can be more descriptive in your question in order to receive a good and accurate answer.

As far as I understand - I can propose you to use the Reporting capabilities ot SQL Server: Go to SQL Server Management Studio -> right click on the desired DB -> Reports -> Custom Reports -> Disk usage, etc. 
This is per database reporting.

As for the RAM usage you can browse here:
[How much RAM is SQL Server actually using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289558/how-much-ram-is-sql-server-actually-using)

Comment: Disk usage <> RAM usage

Comment: Sir, i want SQLserver.exe memory utilization by SQL query or by c# programming.