# SQL Server does not use the assigned memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

We use

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

The machine has 70GB Memory

The SQL Server has

- minimum Server memory: 20480 MB
- maximum Server memory: 51200 MB

But when I open the Resourcemonitor and check the memory of sqlserver.exe-process, I see that the Commited Memory (Zugesichert) is about 51GB, but the WorkingSet (Arbeitssatz) and Privat are only about 1GB.

[image]

The SQL Server is under full load and it is running for 3 month without restart.

The Page Lifetime Expectancy is 14'146s (=about 4h)

For testing purpose, I have selected a table with 3.5Mio Rows (Storage Size: 4'600MB) - but the values for WorkingSet and Private in the Resourcemonitor do not change.

Now my questions:

- Is there something wrong or are the values of Resourcemonitor not correct?
- If yes, where can I get the real memory usages?
- If no, where can I take in to solve the problem or get more information?

Comment: Look into the local security privilege "Lock pages in memory" for your SQL Server windows service account - it will allow you to force SQL Server to keep tables in memory.

Comment: What is your server **Edition**? Please update your post with the result of select @@version

Comment: @sepupic Thank you for your hint. I have added the information.

Comment: Ok for edition, it's not limited in any way. What does Perfmon show?

Comment: @sepupic Which Counter should I monitor to get the right information?

Comment: In the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289558/how-much-ram-is-sql-server-actually-using you can find correct counters